# Is $(x)\otimes_{k[x]/(x^2)}(x)$ zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

> I am trying to decide if $(x)\otimes_{k[x]/(x^2)}(x)$ is zero.

So I considered $x \otimes x$ which I rewrote as $1 \otimes x^2 = 1 \otimes 0 = 0$. But then I realized that $1$ does not live in $(x)$. Now I am unsure how to proceed. Also it's beginning to feel like $x \otimes x \neq 0$. Thanks.

Comment: You're instinct to pull the $x$ through the tensor product is good, but you leave behind $1$, which is not an element of $(x)$, so it's not allowed in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $A = k\left[x\right]/\left(x^2\right)$, and let us denote the projection of $x \in k\left[x\right]$ onto $A$ by $x$ (by abuse of notation). I assume that your $\left(x\right)$ means the $A$-submodule of $A$ spanned by $x$. And your question is: Is $\left(x\right) \otimes_A \left(x\right) = 0$ ?

I claim that the answer is "No". Indeed, there is an $A$-bilinear map $\left(x\right) \times \left(x\right) \to k\left[x\right]/\left(x\right)$ (note that the right hand side of this is an $A$-module, in the obvious way) sending every $\left(xa,xb\right)$ to the projection of $ab$. You need to check that this map is well-defined (any given element of $\left(x\right)$ can be written as $xa$ for several different polynomials $a$, and you need to check that they all lead to the same $ab$). But once this is proven, it follows that there is a nonzero $A$-bilinear map from $\left(x\right) \times \left(x\right)$ to an $A$-bimodule (indeed, this map is clearly nonzero, as it sends $\left(x,x\right)$ to $1$). But this map factors through $\left(x\right) \otimes_A \left(x\right)$. Thus, $\left(x\right) \otimes_A \left(x\right)$ cannot be $0$ (or else it would factor through $0$, which flies in the face of its being nonzero).

Actually it is easy to see that $\left(x\right) \otimes_A \left(x\right) \cong k\left[x\right] / \left(x\right)$, and also the $A$-module $\left(x\right)$ itself is isomorphic to $k\left[x\right] / \left(x\right)$.

Comment: Do you mean $k[x]/(x^2)$ or $k[x]/(x)$? It seems strange that $(x) \otimes_A (x)$ will be a field.

Comment: I mean what I say. $k\left[x\right]/\left(x\right)$ is a quotient ring of $k\left[x\right]/\left(x^2\right)=A$ (since the ideal $\left(x^2\right)$ is contained in the ideal $\left(x\right)$), and thus an $A$-algebra.

Comment: It is not right to say that $\left(x\right)\otimes_A\left(x\right)$ will be a field. We are tensoring $A$-modules here, not $A$-algebras, since $\left(x\right)$ is not an $A$-algebra (unless you allow for algebras without unity, and then the isomorphisms become wrong). So what happens is that the tensor product of two $A$-modules is an $A$-module which happens to be isomorphic to each of these two $A$-modules. Might look surprising, but not that much: You generally have $\left(B/I\right) \otimes_B \left(B/I\right) \cong B/I$ whenever $B$ is a commutative ring and $I$ is an ideal of $B$.

Comment: (Even more generally, if $B$ is a commutative ring and $I$ and $J$ are two ideals of $B$, then $\left(B/I\right) \otimes_B \left(B/J\right) \cong B/\left(I+J\right)$. This is actually proven somewhere either on MO or on m.se.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time darij.

Answer (score 6):

The following observations are made en passant in the accepted answer. I think they deserve a full proof.

> Let $R=K[X]/(X^2)$, and $x$ be the residue class of $X$ modulo the ideal $(X^2)$. Then $$\operatorname{Ann}_R(x)=Rx.$$

Since $x^2=0$ we have $Rx\subseteq\operatorname{Ann}_R(x)$. For the converse, let $f(x)\in\operatorname{Ann}_R(x)$. Then $f(x)x=0\Rightarrow f(X)X\in(X^2)\Rightarrow f(X)\in(X)\Rightarrow f(x)\in Rx$.

Since $Rx\simeq R/\operatorname{Ann}_R(x)$ we get $Rx\simeq R/Rx$, and this gives us $$Rx\otimes_RRx\simeq R/Rx\otimes_RR/Rx\simeq R/Rx.$$